# How do I find a subtext without comma using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame as:

```
result <- c('Ab1 : 256 ug/mL(R), Ab2(disk); 18mm(S)', 'Ab1 : 4 ug/mL(S), Ab2(disk); <2mm(R)')
df <- data.frame(result)
```

What should I do if I would like to check whether '(R)' appears after 'antibiotics1' ?

```
grep("Ab1[[:print:]]*\\(R\\)", result)
```

gives

```
[1] 1 2
```

while the result I want is

```
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep("Ab1[^(]*?\\(R\\)", result)
[1] 1

Ab1      match 'Ab1' literally
[^(]*?   match anything besides an opening parenthesis, non greedily
(R)      match '(R)' literally
```

In the second case, it is not possible to do this match without first consuming at least one opening parenthesis, hence only the first matches.

Comment: may be we could further simplify the regex to `grep("Ab1[^(]*\\(R\\)", result)`

Comment: Thank you. It surely does work finding whether '(R)' is after 'Ab1'